# How can I create url rewrites in ASP.Net Core at runtime?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, url-rewriting, asp.net-core-mvc

For creating a local diskcache of resized images, I am trying to figure out how I can create a URL rewrite during runtime.

Something like this:

```
[Route("(images/{id}.jpg")]
public IActionResult ResizeImage(int id, int height, int width)
{
    string webRoot = _env.ContentRootPath;
    var file = System.IO.Path.Combine(webRoot, $"resizedimage{id}.jpg");
    //Pseudocode:
    UrlRewriter.DoMagic($"images/{id}.jpg?height={height}&width={width}", "/resizedimage{id}.jpg")
    return File(file, "image/jpeg");
}
```

A client requests /images/123.jpg?height=100&width=100 ...

I can create a static url rewrite, that rewrites /images/123.jpg?height=100&width=100 to /images/resizedimage.jpg (resized image on disk), bypassing the action method (presumably)..

How can I do the same thing on the fly, with something like the above pseudocode?

Note:

- I do not care about the first request, which WILL hit the actionmethod and be served the image via a fileresult (as shown above), only subsequent requests to the same url.
- I am aware of methods to create dynamic url rewrites at startup, but not runtime (which is what I am asking about)
- Yes, I could just return a redirect to the image file, which is also pretty efficient - but it is still two synchrounous requests from the client.
- ASP.Net Core 2+ required

Comment: I don't understand why use url rewrite if you are serving the file from the action method. can you please explain to me?

Comment: @ElvisJr Url rewrites happens on a lower level, so it works just as if the file was being served directly from /image/myimage.jpg, whereas returning it from an actionmethod requires server processing (which is an extra layer - slower at scale).

Comment: If your looking for performance you may want to set the rewrites rules at server level and not app level, or write your middleware to deal with this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easiest way to do this is that injecting `RewriteOptions` to controller and then adding rules to it but `RewriteOptions.Rules` is not thread-safe.

You need custom rule and thread-safe collection. Something like this should work:

**Startup:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<ImageRewriteCollection>();
    // ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().Add(new ImageRewriteRule(app.ApplicationServices.GetService<ImageRewriteCollection>())));
    // ...
}
```

**ImageRewriteCollection:**

```
public class ImageRewriteCollection
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<(int id, int width, int height), string> imageRewrites
        = new ConcurrentDictionary<(int id, int width, int height), string>();

    public bool TryAdd(int id, int width, int height, string path)
        => imageRewrites.TryAdd((id, width, height), path);

    public bool TryGetValue(int id, int width, int height, out string path)
        => imageRewrites.TryGetValue((id, width, height), out path);
}
```

**ImageRewriteRule:**

```
public class ImageRewriteRule : IRule
{
    private readonly ImageRewriteCollection rewriteCollection;
    private readonly Regex pathRegex = new Regex("^/images/(\\d+).jpg");

    public ImageRewriteRule(ImageRewriteCollection rewriteCollection)
    {
        this.rewriteCollection = rewriteCollection;
    }

    public void ApplyRule(RewriteContext context)
    {
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
        var pathMatch = pathRegex.Match(request.Path.Value);
        if (pathMatch.Success)
        {
            bool isValidPath = true;
            int id = int.Parse(pathMatch.Groups[1].Value);

            int width = 0;
            int height = 0;
            string widthQuery = request.Query["width"];
            string heightQuery = request.Query["height"];

            if (widthQuery == null || !int.TryParse(widthQuery, out width))
                isValidPath = false;

            if (heightQuery == null || !int.TryParse(heightQuery, out height))
                isValidPath = false;

            if (isValidPath && rewriteCollection.TryGetValue(id, width, height, out string path))
            {
                request.Path = path;
                context.Result = RuleResult.SkipRemainingRules;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
private readonly ImageRewriteCollection rewriteCollection;

public HomeController(ImageRewriteCollection rewriteCollection)
{
    this.rewriteCollection = rewriteCollection;
}

[Route("images/{id}.jpg")]
public IActionResult ResizeImage(int id, int width, int height)
{
    rewriteCollection.TryAdd(id, width, height, "/resizedimagepath...");
    return File();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a middleware to do the rewrite - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: As far as I can tell, all the examples on that page rely on static rules set up on application startup - not added dynamically during runtime, as I need. Please correct me if I am wrong.